# Relative import in python-django application is not working

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror, python-module

I have a file `eventbrite_data.py` inside the commands folder as you see in the below image:

[image]

Inside the file I am trying to call a class from `models.py` and I tried different variations but I am getting `an error`:

```
from .models import Activity
ImportError: No module named models
```

**Things tried so far**

From inside the `eventbrite_data.py` file, I tried to call `models.py` using the following variations so far:

```
from activites.models import Activity
from source.activites.models import Activity
from .models import Activity
```

Sadly, All are resulting into `import error`. I am running the script using `python manage.py eventbrite_data` and `virtual environment is activated` . Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single dot `.models` means it will look in the same directory as the current file.  It's looking for */commands/models.py*, which doesn't exist.

Two dots `..model` means it's going to go two directories up.  It would look for */management/models.py*, which also doesn't exist.

In your case, you need to go 3 directories up, to look for */activities/models.py*

```
from ...models import Activity
```

Comment: Don't know why but suddenly `from activites.models import Activity` started working